# Making a specified color Transparent?

Tags: visual-c++, c++-cli

I am programming in windows visual C++, and I am trying to make a specific color transparent. I have asked this question before but all I got was answer including C code, not C++/CLI. P.s This is a windows form application...
I think the previous code I received as an answer was similar to this.

Color pixelColor = myBitmap.GetPixel(1, 1);

but that is C code... not C++/CLI. How do you make a PictureBoxes image have a transparent color in it?

Comment: C++ is mostly a superset of C, and C++/CLI is mostly a superset of C++. There's nothing wrong with the code snippet you show, so what's your *real* problem?

Comment: I get this error... 1>c:\users\devon\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\retaliation\retaliation\Form1.h(467): error C2039: 'GetPixel' : is not a member of 'System::Windows::Forms::PictureBox'
1>          c:\program files (x86)\reference assemblies\microsoft\framework\.netframework\v4.0\system.windows.forms.dll : see declaration of 'System::Windows::Forms::PictureBox'

Comment: The question doesn't make a wholeheckofalot of sense.  A color is transparent when it has an alpha of 0, the actual color doesn't matter anymore since you cannot see it anyway.  If you want to make a specific color in a bitmap transparent then use the Bitmap::MakeTransparent() method.  You'll need to cast the PictureBox::Image property to Bitmap to get a reference to the Bitmap object.  Use safe_cast<> in a C++/CLI program.

Answer (score 0):

You must work on the picture itself (`System::Drawing::Image` or `System::Drawing::Bitmap`), not the Windows Forms component that displays it.

Comment: It's not a namespace, it's a ref class. In the System::Drawing namespace, in the System.Drawing assembly.